# NullPayload for Database Query only when wrapped in a Transaction

Tags: transactions, mule

I have a flow which always returns NullPayload when wrapped in a multi-transaction. When I remove the multi-transaction tag I get the expected results. Why is that? Here is the code snippet

```
<flow name="successful-flow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="order-process.in" doc:name="VM"/>
    <ee:multi-transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional" >
        <foreach collection="#[message.payload]" doc:name="For Each"
        rootMessageVariableName="Original">
            <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="orders.queue"
            connector-ref="jmsConnector" doc:name="JMS - Send to Order Processing Queue">
            <jms:transaction action="JOIN_IF_POSSIBLE"/>
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        </foreach>
    <db:insert config-ref="ORDER_DB" doc:name="Save Orders" >
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into orders(PRODUCT_ID,LINE_ITEM_CODE,PRICE,LST_UPDT_TMSP) VALUES('XXT665,'TP',20.99,'09/09/2010')]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
    </ee:multi-transactional>
    <response>
        <db:select config-ref="ORDER_DB" doc:name="Database" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_JOIN">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select count(*) from orders]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
    </response>
    <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Order Processing Exception">
        <logger
            message="Error  during  flow - #[message] :: Exception::= #  [exception.summaryMessage]"
            level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger" />
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the previous transaction will not have finished and been committed. The default transactionalAction for the select query is JOIN_IF_POSSIBLE which means I will be reading the data before the data was inserted and committed.  Simple fix is as follows:

```
<response>
    <db:select config-ref="ORDER_DB" doc:name="Database" transactionalAction="NOT_SUPPORTED">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select count(*) from orders]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
</response>
```